# Death via ability damage vs magic items

Tags: dnd-3.5e, damage

I'm looking for a clarification on how reducing an ability to 0 is affected by magic items that increase that ability.  For instance, a character with CON 18 is wearing a belt of Constitution +2, giving it an effective CON of 20.  How much CON damage can this PC take before dying?  Is it 18, as that's their 'base' CON, or is it 20?  If it's 20, is it true that if they take 18 points of CON damage, and then the belt is removed, the character dies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While wearing the belt, the character’s Constitution is 20, for any and all purposes. The character could qualify for feats or prestige classes that require 19 or 20 Constitution (can’t think of any, but if they exist, this would count), dies only after taking 20 Constitution damage, has a +5 Constitution modifier for bonus HP, Concentration, Fortitude, and Constitution checks, and so on. The game only cares what the total number is; there isn’t even a good way within the rules text of *indicating* what you mean if bonuses aren’t to be included.

If the belt is removed, the character’s Constitution is now 18. The character’s HP goes down, Concentration and Fortitude bonuses go down, and now no longer qualifies for things that require 19 or 20 Constitution. The latter means they cannot use feats they qualified for. (What happens with prestige classes is debatable; the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* says you only need to meet prerequisites to take your first level, while *Complete Warrior* says you lose your class features – except *Complete Warrior* doesn’t, under the rules, have the authority to change what the *DMG* says, and moreover that rule is nonsensical if applied to some non-*Complete Warrior* classes, like the *DMG*’s dragon disciple).

If the character, while wearing the belt, takes 18 Constitution damage, they are at 2 Constitution. Removing the belt at this point would result in their death.

Comment: Thats why I wear suspenders

Comment: Interesting.  So the damaged Con is not lost first?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer The game has no notion of “temporary” ability scores, as it does for temporary hit points. So no, there is no special treatment for the Constitution added by an item; when you remove the item, your Constitution goes down by 2, no matter what other changes have applied.